# How do i work with two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I constructed (poorly) a two dimensional array to hold student names and the grades. It does prompt me for the names of students equal to the amount that i want, but it dosn't for grades. Also it states that i have a index out of bounds, which i dont see how that happened.

```
private void studentArray() {
            int rows = 0;
            int col = 0;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("How many students do you have?");
            rows = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("How many tests would you like to record?");
            col = input.nextInt();

           String [][] schoolArray =  new String[rows][col];

           for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++ ){
            System.out.println("Please enter student name.");
            schoolArray[row][0] = input.next();
                for(int cols = 1; cols < col; cols++){
                System.out.println("Please enter grades.");
                schoolArray[cols][0] = input.next();
                }//end of col for loop
        }//end of row for loop
           printSchool (schoolArray, rows, col);


        }//end of studentArray

        private void printSchool(String[][]schoolArray, int rows, int col){
            for ( int row = 0; row < schoolArray.length; row ++) {
                System.out.print(schoolArray[rows][col + 1] + "\t");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Change `for (int cols = 1; cols < col; cols++){` to `for (int cols = 0; cols < col; cols++){` and `schoolArray[cols][0] = input.next();` to `schoolArray[row][1] = input.next();` and just eliminate that `cols` loop. You only have two columns.

Comment: We are supposed to have the amount of grades determine the amount of columns, now it asks me the correct amount of times, but when it should display it gives an index out of bounds

Comment: @donovanlinder thats because you are using the `row` and `col` variables. which hold the value of how many rows and how many cols

Comment: What should i use instead then??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written this by mistake `school[cols][0]` it should be `school[row][cols]` inside col for loop

Answer (score 0):

First use-

```
schoolArray[row][cols] = input.next();
```

instead of

```
schoolArray[cols][0] = input.next();
```

and also change the printSchool method-

```
 private void printSchool(String[][]schoolArray, int rows, int col){
                for ( int row = 0; row < rows; row ++) {
                       System.out.print("\n");
                       for(int cols= 0; cols < col ;cols++){

                    System.out.print(schoolArray[row][cols] + "\t");
                  }
                }
            }
```